# Adding a new node to a list

Tags: c, linked-list, char

Hey so i am wondering how i would go about adding a new node to a list. So have a container that holds the list, which i need to add too. Which is defined as follows. 
This is the container for the list

```
struct vm
{
    struct vm_list * item_list;
    struct coin * coins;
    char * foodfile;
    char * coinsfile;
};
```

this is the list that holds node.

```
struct vm_list
{
    struct vm_node * head;
    unsigned length;
};
```

this is the definition of the node

```
struct vm_node
{
    struct stock_item * data;
    struct vm_node * next;
};
```

this is how i am attempting to add an item to the list.

```
BOOLEAN add_item(struct vm* vm)
{
    struct stock_item *newItem;
    newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct stock_item));
    struct vm_node *newNode; //setup a new item to store the data in.
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    struct vm_node *VMP; //setup the new Node to hold the newItem
    VMP = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    struct vm_node *VMF; //too keep track of the first element in the list. So i can print out the list from the start.
    VMF = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    VMF->next = vm->item_list->head;
/* the following loops through until it finds the last element in the list. Which it stores in the VMP structure. So we can increment the ID counter by 1.*/
    while(vm->item_list->head){
        VMP->data = vm->item_list->head->data; //stores the last element of the linked list. Allowing us to add information to the nth bottom of the list.
        vm->item_list->head = vm->item_list->head->next;
    }
/* defining the items to be stored in the newItem struct. */
    char *newName;
    char *newDesc;
    char * onHand;
    char *price;
    newName = malloc(sizeof(char));
    newDesc = malloc(sizeof(char));
    price = malloc(sizeof(char));
    onHand = malloc(sizeof(char));
    char *dem = VMP->data->id; //returns the ID of the last item in the list.
    int change = atoi(&dem[4]); //changes the item to a int.
    change++; //increments by 1.
    char str;
    sprintf(&str, "%d", change); // converts back to char.
    dem[4]=str; // stores back in the char array.
    read_rest_of_line(); //buffer handler.
    printf("Enter the item name: ");
    newName = getlines();
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the item description: ");
    newDesc = getlines();
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter how many will be stocked: ");
    onHand = getlines();
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much will the item cost: ");
    price = getlines();
    printf("\n");
//adding a new item to the list.
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newItem  = add_tobottomoflist(dem,newName,newDesc,onHand,price); //add_tobottom is setups the newItem.
    newNode->data = newItem; // sets the data for newNode = to newItem
    vm->item_list->head = newNode; //sets up the new Node.
    vm->item_list->head->next = VMF; //points to the first element in the list for linking.
    display_items(vm); // displays all the elements in the list.

    /* The UNUSED() function is designed to prevent warnings while your
     * code is only partially complete. Delete this function call once
     * you are using vm in your own code */
    UNUSED(vm);
    return FALSE;
}
```

The **output** when the code is ran is as follows.

```
IO        NAME                Description                                                           On Hand        price
I0006     Nam
                desc
                                                                 12             $3.04
p�                                                                                                -2108446504    $-2108446504.32615
I0001     Coke                375 ml Can of coke                                                    50             $3.50
I0002     Pepsi               375 ml Can of pepsi                                                   20             $3.00
I0003     Lemon Cheesecake    A delicious, 1/8 size slice of cheesecake                             10             $4.00
I0004     Mars Bar            A delicious 50 g Mars Bar chilled just the way you like it.           20             $3.00
I0006     Lemon Tart          A delicious lemon butter tart with a pastry based                     12             $3.75
```

The lemon tart id should be equal to `I0005` not `I0006`, i have no idea where it has incremented, and the new item has been added to the beginning of the list not at the end. There also appears to be a `null` object at the start of the list also.
Any thoughts on what could be happening here?

Comment: Your add shouldn't be doing all that, specifically asking questions. Get all this stuff prior to the insert then do it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils huh?

Comment: Anyway, it's not an ordered list is it?

Comment: You keep saying `malloc(sizeof(char));` I do not think that means what you think it means. Especially when you then throw that memory right away with `newName = getlines();` and friends.

Comment: Its suppose to be an ordered list. Doesnt malloc just allocate memory specificallu for the char? Or am i not required to malloc?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char));` is identical to `malloc(1);` It allocates memory for a single `char`, which is big enough to store an empty string, but not any other kind of string. But there's no point `malloc()`ing anything if you're just going to throw it away. You don't show the definition of `getlines()`, but hopefully that's `malloc()`ing some memory for you.

Comment: Sadly, people learn about data structures like linked lists without learning their computational characteristics and what data structures to use in what contexts. The whole point of singly-linked lists with just a pointer to head is that items should only be added *at the beginning*, never at the end . If you want to add to the end, use a queue (which can be implemented as a linked list with pointers to both the first and last elements) or a deque (which can be implemented as a doubly linked list) or a resizable array.

Comment: "Doesnt malloc just allocate memory specificallu for the char" -- malloc does what its documentation says ... `malloc(n)` allocates `n` bytes. It's rare to want to allocate precisely 1 char (though such applications do exist).

Comment: There are scarily many things wrong with this code, like `char str;
    sprintf(&str, "%d", change);`, which is undefined behavior, and the whole block of code around that. I suggest sitting down with a more experienced C programmer friend, teacher, or tutor to work through this.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple things that are problematic.
One, the null thing you have at the beginning is `VMF`. your comments say that this variable is to keep track of the beginning of the list. You already have `head` for that. Why are you mallocing more memory for this `VMF`?

You seem to be trying to modify existing code that adds to the beginning of the list, instead of the end. To add to the end, you have to change your while loop. In your while loop, iterate through the list, and keep track of the last node that isn't null. Then point `last_node->next` to your new node

Comment: Thanks there must be a gap in my understanding ill do a bit research.